# How to use Typescript, Jest and Axios to mock two different requests in the same unit test?

Tags: javascript, typescript, unit-testing, axios, ts-jest

So I have `function A` and `function B`

`function A` does a GET request

`function B` does a GET request

`function B` is inside `function A`

I want to test the `function A`, and in order to do that I need to mock two GET requests(one mock for each function) to different endpoints with different responses. How can I do that using `Jest` and `Axios`?

I couldn't figure out how to mock the second call:

```
it("test", async () => {
    mock.get.mockResolvedValue({ data: RESPONSE });

    const response = await functionA(input);

    expect(response).toMatchObject({ status: 1 });
    expect(response.value).toMatchObject({
      state: { status: "OK" },
      data: RESPONSE,
    });
  });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This solved my problem:

```
mock.get.mockImplementation((url) => {
      switch (url) {
        case 'URL_A':
          return Promise.resolve({data: data_A})
        case 'URL_B':
          return Promise.resolve({data: data_B})
        default:
          return Promise.reject(new Error('error message'))
      }
    })
```

Answer (score 1):

A good alternative could be to use the `mockResolvedValueOnce(...)` method. Something like this:

```js
const DATA_A = 'a';
const DATA_B = 'b';
mock.get.mockResolvedValue('default')
    .mockResolvedValueOnce(DATA_A)
    .mockResolvedValueOnce(DATA_B);
```

Comment: How the answer would be using `mockResolvedValueOnce(...)` ?

Comment: I added a more spoon-feeding to the answer so it's clear.